# SQL Server CE GROUP BY clause

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have to use `GROUP BY` statement to pull data from SQL Server CE.

Now I'm getting

> *In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain
>   only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = ,Date ]*

but I really want to get date.

Query is as follows

```
SELECT Date 
FROM Installments 
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING Sr = max(Sr)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please explain

Comment: It might be worth explaining just what you want the query to do in English rather than SQL. I can think of a couple of ways to "fix" this so it gives an answer, but they'd each have different answers and I don't know which you'd actually want.

Comment: @Jon Hanna can you join me in chat where i can explain you the schema and what i want to get

Comment: Well, no point if ElVieejo already hit on the answer you needed. Hurray! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use group by, you group by some field, and apply an aggregate function.
So, in the select, you shoud that field (the grouped result) and then the result of the function used.

Maybe you want something like

```
SELECT Id, Max(date) FROM Installments GROUP BY ID
```

It will depends on what you want.

Read about [Group by here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173245%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping by ID, then each group could potentially have multiple different dates, so you can't select Date.  You could, for example,

```
select Max(Date) FROM Installments GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need to include the columns you're returning in the group by clause.

```
SELECT Date FROM Installments GROUP BY ID, Date
```

I suspect what you may be trying to do is this

```
SELECT Date
FROM Installments
WHERE sr = (Select MAX(sr) from Installments)
```

Comment: but now it says same for HAVING CALUSE Says "In aggregate and grouping expressions, the HAVING clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = Sr ]"